# calling method to a main in java

Tags: java, methods, method-call

I'm writing a program that calculates the hypotenuse of a triangle, and I'm supposed to call up a method into the main.

Is it better to have them in 2 separate files, or to have the method I'm calling up in the program I'm running?

In the program, I keep getting error messages about the last line of code, with the JOptionPane output.

What am I getting wrong?

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class A2
{   

     public static double Hypo(double a,double b,double c);
        double a,b,c;
        {
            hyp=((a*a)+(b*b));
            c=Math.sqrt(hyp);
        }

    int x,y;
    double c;
    String text1=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("How long is side A? ");
    int x=Integer.parseInt(text1);
    String text2=JOptionPanes.howInputDialog("How long is side B? ");
    int y=Integer.parseInt(text2);
    double c=A2.Hypo(x,y);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The hypotenuse of the triangle is " +c);
    }
```

Comment: What kind of error do you get?

Comment: Your `Hypo()` method won't work. It has to return a value and it doesn't. It puts a value in `c` but values can't be returned through parameters (primitives at least). And it declares local variables that have no value with the same names as the parameters, thus hiding them. And there is a semicolon after its header, making it abstract.

Comment: I think you lack a lot of basics. 1 question probably can't answer all your doubts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code has so many problems it's hard to know where to begin.

Here's some advice:

1. Good names matter.  You can and must do better than A2 for a class.
2. Learn and follow the Sun Java coding standards.
3. Style and readability matter.  Learn a good code layout and stick to it.

Start with this.  It runs and gives correct results:

```
import javax.swing.*;

/**
 * A2
 * @author Michael
 * @link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30965862/calling-method-to-a-main-in-java
 * @since 6/21/2015 11:00 AM
 */
public class SimpleMathDemo {

    public static double hypotenuse(double a,double b) {
        return Math.sqrt(a*a+b*b);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String text1= JOptionPane.showInputDialog("How long is side A? ");
        int x=Integer.parseInt(text1);
        String text2=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("How long is side B? ");
        int y=Integer.parseInt(text2);
        double c= SimpleMathDemo.hypotenuse(x,y);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The hypotenuse of the triangle is " +c);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Code analysis

```
 public class A2 {

    //Missing method body no return values ..Is this an abstact function?/
    public static double Hypo(double a, double b, double c);
    double a, b, c;

    //Whats this part doing hanging in the middle??
    {
    //where is the variable declaration of hyp
        hyp = ((a * a) + (b * b));
        c = Math.sqrt(hyp);
    }

    int x, y; 
    //variable c is already  declared
    double c;
    String text1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("How long is side A? ");
     //variable x is already  declared
    int x = Integer.parseInt(text1);
    //JOptionPane not JOptionPanes
    String text2 = JOptionPanes.howInputDialog("How long is side B? ");
    //variable y is already  declared
    int y = Integer.parseInt(text2);
     //variable c is already  declared and Hypo function has three arguements in the declaration
    double c = A2.Hypo(x, y);
//wont work because the whole code is buggy
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "The hypotenuse of the triangle is " +c);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate more:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class A2 {

    public static double Hypo(int a, int b) {
        double hyp=((a*a)+(b*b));
        double c=Math.sqrt(hyp);
        return c;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int x, y;
        double c;
        String text1=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("How long is side A? ");
        x=Integer.parseInt(text1);
        String text2=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("How long is side B? ");
        y=Integer.parseInt(text2);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The hypotenuse of the triangle is " + Hypo(x,y));
    }

}
```

You need to choose a correct return type, whether it be void, int, double, etc, and each method with a return type should return a value with the set type.

You also always need at least one main method in a program. There can be multiple in different classes.

You will need to use a more specific variable names, and follow oracle convention for brackets {}.

DO not declare a variable twice as in:

```
int x, y;
int x = 1; // WRONG
x = 1; // Correct
```

Comment: Please provide an explanation for your answer

Comment: @eliasah added explanation.